Volume of a box fromed by countable disjoint boxes
Problem
Let $n>1$. Suppose
\begin{equation}
\prod_{j=1}^n [a_j,b_j)=\bigsqcup_{k=1}^{\infty} \prod_{j=1}^n [a_{j,k},b_{j,k})
\end{equation}
The symbol $\bigsqcup$ means disjoint union.
Prove the following proposition without direct usage of the Lebesgue measure
\begin{equation}
\prod_{j=1}^n(b_j-a_j)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\Big(\prod_{j=1}^n(b_{j,k}-a_{j,k})\Big)
\end{equation}
Note that the $\prod$ in our hypothesis means the Cartesian product, while the $\prod$ in the proposition we wish to prove means the product of the real numbers.

Context and Attempt
I came across this problem when I was learning the Lebesgue measure, which, of course, solved the problem. However, I believe there exists a method that does not require the usage of measure. I can prove that
\begin{equation}\prod_{j=1}^n(b_j-a_j)\geq\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\Big(\prod_{j=1}^n(b_{j,k}-a_{j,k})\Big)
\end{equation}
by showing
\begin{equation}\forall K\in\mathbb{N}, \prod_{j=1}^n(b_j-a_j)\geq\sum_{k=1}^{K}\Big(\prod_{j=1}^n(b_{j,k}-a_{j,k})\Big)
\end{equation}
which is proved by cutting the $\prod_{j=1}^n [a_j,b_j)$ into a finite amount of "grids." To me, the same idea of cutting boxes into grids seems impossible to show the reverse inequality since it becomes a circular argument when we are cutting the boxes into an infinite amount of grids. Note that all answers that do not use measure are welcomed, and note that I put in the hypothesis $n>1$ because the case is simple if $n=1$.

In this document Proposition 2.7 the reverse inequality is proved. It is phrased in a measure theoretic way because it is used to establish the existence of the Lebesgue measure
